# Frobenius theorem on real division algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can someone help me with this? I don't understand conclusion after Exercise 7, that A is direct sum of eigenspaces U(1) and U(-1). Thanks in advance :)
http://danshved.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/frobenius-theorem-on-real-division-algebras/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the invertible linear map $\phi$ satisfies the equation $X^2-1=0$, the minimal polynomial of $\phi$ divides $x^2-1$. Hence $\phi$ is diagonalizable, and has eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$.
Hence there is a basis of eigenvectors, i.e., $U(1)\oplus U(-1)=A$. For details see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459114/find-all-the-linear-involutions-f-e-to-e-where-e-is-a-finite-dimensional).