# If $D$ is a $3\times 3$-matrix of order $6$, then the geometric multiplicity of eigenvalue $-1$ in $D^3$ is two

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Consider the subgroup $H \le \operatorname{GL}(3,3)$ generated by the two matrices
$$
 A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
 \quad\mbox{ and }\quad
 B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
If $D \in H$ has order $6$, then I want to show that $D^3$ is diagonalisable as
$$
 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
i.e. the eigenvalue $-1$ has geometric multiplicity $2$. I know that as $D^3$ is involutory that $\pm 1$ are the only eigenvalues, also see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459114/find-all-the-linear-involutions-f-e-to-e-where-e-is-a-finite-dimensional). Also of course $x^6 - 1 = (x^3 - 1)(x^3 + 1) = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$, so this polynomial is divided by the minimal polynomial of $D^6$, but I do not see if this might be helpful?

Comment: @Bernard But not when $D^6 = I$ and $D^i \ne I$ for $i =1,2,3,4,5$; I added that to the question (sorry forgot that). For the other comment: That might be possible too, but what is essential is that *both* eigenvalues occur, and not just $I$ or $-I$ (but I conjecture that $-1$ has to occur twice)

Comment: I rewrote the title to coincide with the clarified question.

Comment: OK, it's clearer now.

Comment: Also, over $\Bbb{F}_3$ we have the factorization
$$x^6-1=(x^2-1)^3=(x-1)^3(x+1)^3.$$ This may come in handy. In other words, the quadratic polynomials in your factorization are not irreducible modulo three.

Comment: It looks like (read, I haven't checked, but this is an educated guess) $H$ is the group of monomial matrices with determinant $+1$. That has order 24. Its diagonal matrices form a normal subgroup $N$ of order four, and $H/N\simeq S_3$. Wonder how that will help?

Comment: Well, if an element has order six, the $S_3$ part must be a 3-cycle. This implies that $D^3$ is itself diagonal, not just diagonalizable. That settles the question I think :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What do you mean by "$\mathcal S_3$ part", $H$ is not a semi-direct product where we can decompose as $N \rtimes H/N$? And why does this forces that $-1$ occurs twice on the diagonal?

Comment: You're right. It is not the semi-direct product. At least it isn't clear to me why it would be. But it is an index two subgroup of the semidirect product $G=C_2^3\rtimes S_3$, Where that Cartesian power of $C_2$ consists of the diagonal matrices. $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that all the matrices in $H$ have determinant $+1$. I added another answer. Turns out I didn't need to figure out the order of $H$.

Comment: So we have a homomorphism from $H$ to $S_3$ that simply replaces all the $-1$ entries with $1$s. And  (with a bit of hindsight) what I called *the $S_3$ part* really is the image under that homomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer deals with the specified group $H$.

---

The matrices $A$ and $B$ are both *monomial* matrices, i.e. they have a single non-zero entry on each row and column. Furthermore, they both have determinant one. Because monomial matrices form a group, and $SL_3(\Bbb{F}_3)$ is a group, we see that these two properties are shared by all the matrices in $H$.

Let's say that a matrix $D\in H$ belongs to the permutation $\sigma\in S_3$, if the non-zero entry of column $j$ appears on row $\sigma(j)$. It is easy to see that if $D$ belongs to the permutation $\sigma$, then $D^k$ belongs to the permutation $\sigma^k$. Therefore $\ell=\operatorname{ord}(\sigma)$ is the lowest power of $D$ that is diagonal. Because the non-zero elements of $\Bbb{F}_3$ are $\pm1$, we see that the order of $D$ is then either $\ell$ or $2\ell$.

We were given that $D$ has order $6$. Because $\ell\in\{1,2,3\}$ we must have $\ell=3$. And because $D$ had order $6$, we know that $D^3$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $\pm1$, not all $=1$. Because $\det D^3=1$, we can deduce that the number of entries $=-1$ in $D^3$ is exactly two. Q.E.D.

Comment: Thank you! Let me add that your conclusions about the order could be drawn as we have a homomorphism on $\mathcal S_3$ as you wrote in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to an earlier version of the question, when the subgroup was not specified.

---

Collecting some of my comments to an answer. The claim is false as stated.
The order six matrix
$$
D=\pmatrix{-1&1&0\cr0&-1&0\cr0&0&-1\cr}
$$
raised to third power gives $-I$ and thus has $-1$ as an eigenvalue of multiplicity three.

Similarly another order six matrix
$$
D=\pmatrix{1&1&0\cr0&1&0\cr0&0&-1\cr}
$$
has as the cube the diagonal matrix with $1$ occuring twice and $-1$ once.

These examples show that

- it is not necessarily the case that both $+1$ and $-1$ occur as eigenvalues (one of the formulations of the question from the comments)
- $D^3$ may have $-1$ as an eigenvalue with multiplicity one only.

---

Given this I'm still wondering what the question really was?

---

Observe that any Jordan block of size two or three can be written in the form
$$
J=rI+N,
$$
where $N^3=0$. Because we are in characteristic three and $I$ and $N$ commute, the binomial formula gives
$$
J^3=r^3I+3r^2N+3rN^2+N^3=r^3I.
$$
This helped me in constructing those examples.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Mhh, I edited the question to just consider a special subgroup instead of the whole of $\operatorname{GL}(3,3)$, now I am unsure, would it be better to open a new question so that your answer could stand as it is?

Comment: Probably not. I marked the answer as belonging to an earlier version.