# $A$ is a $3 × 3$ matrix and $A^2=I$ then how to prove that $A$ can be diagonalized?

Tags: linear-algebra

Just come across a lecture about eigenvalues and vectors; I don't know how to make a proof if there is no chance to use the algebraic & geometric multiplicity.

Comment: Or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/459205)? (More direct and elementary explicit diagonalization)

Comment: If $A$ is complex or real, then also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1013429/11619) has answers. If the entries can be from a field of characteristic two, then the claim is not true in general.

Comment: Also, I recommend that you read [our abridged guide to new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/11619). Your question is arguably lacking in context and such. Basically this what a dumped homework assignment looks like. I'm not saying it is an assignment. It looks like one, and therefore it raises eyebrows.